# Django ModuleNotFoundError all of a sudden

Tags: python, django

All of a sudden, my django project is not working anymore. Not only my actual branch but even master. This happened after coming back to my project after the night. The error I have is when I run any command I have this message :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pur_beurre.pur_beurre'
```

(Note : pur_beurre is the name of my project)

When I run python manage.py, I have the list of all possible commands plus this new message in red :

```
Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: No module named 'pur_beurre.pur_beurre').
```

I tried to put pur_beurre and pur_beurre.pur_beurre in my installed app in settings.py but its not working.

```
PS C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\pur_beurre> python .\manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 66, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 73, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pur_beurre.pur_beurre'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 386, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 208, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 144, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\Documents\OpenClassrooms\p8\code\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\tdechanet.TWM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pur_beurre.pur_beurre'
```

Here is my installed apps :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main_site.apps.MainSiteConfig',
    'user_management.apps.UserManagementConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: Have you activated the corresponding virtualenv?

Comment: @Dauros Yes I did

Comment: Could you share the whole traceback error message?

Comment: @Dauros I added it to the question

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally deleted the folder pur_beurre with settings.py inside?

Comment: @Razenstein Nop, still there. Plus, as I said, the app don't work on master branch either.

Comment: Could you share your `INSTALLED_APPS` from `settings.py`, and could you tell me where are the `settings.py` and `manage.py` files located?

Comment: @Dauros Done the edit on the question. My manage.py is in the first folder pur_beurre and the settings.py in my second folder pur_beurre.

Comment: So far everything seems fine to me. In your `manage.py` file the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env var has been set to `pur_beurre.settings`, right?

Comment: @Dauros Yes, but the problem happened when I was messing with this variable to setup test coverage. I set it wrongly in my environment variables and I deleted it and close vscode and opened it again. Still not working :/

Comment: Ok, but this is an important detail of the question then. :) What's the value of `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in the venv? `echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` should work in PS as well.

Comment: @Dauros Yeah, I should have put it in the question. echo doesn't return anything.

Comment: When you were "messing with this variable", where did you set this env var? If you search for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` string in VS Code, what's the result? Normally it is only in `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` files. Maybe you find another forgotten place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241337/discussion-between-barthelemy-dechanet-and-dauros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first line in manage.py is

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'pur_beurre.settings')
```

which sets the standard path to settings BUT only as default if DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE has not been defined on system level.

Your error message looks like you have defined on windows a environement variabel DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="pur_beurre.pur_beurre"

just to check add this line in manage.py at the beginning:

```
print(os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'])
```

Then check windows settings for the variabel, correct or delete and just in case reboot.

Comment: Ok so it seem to be the problem. When I print DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE I have pur_beurre.pur_beurre.settings. No the problem is I can't set it to pur_beurre.settings. When use set or go directly in windows settings it doesn't work either, even if I reset vscode.

Comment: Well I added os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "pur_beurre.settings". It's working but I guess it's a bad practice and I don't get why I can't set the environment variable.

Comment: The print/definition was just to make sure thats the problem! Not for longterm. Now at least it is clear that somewhere is that system variable set on windows level. It is difficult to find which app is doing that. I have never worked with vscode